# Angular get image from backend laravel

Tags: angularjs, angular, laravel

i want to get my image from my backend laravel to frontend angular .. my images path is "storage/app/profiles/filename"
 my route :

```
 Route::get('storage/app/profiles/{filename}', function ($filename)
 {
 $file = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get($filename);
 return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
 });
```

when i try to get image using postman i had this exception "FileNotFoundException"

Comment: where did you upload your file?

Comment: at heroku server

Comment: did you have solution ?

Comment: check this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-get-image-from-laravel-and-show-in-angular/